# How to split a 2d numpy array vertically into a new 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this code that essentially splits a two-dimensional numpy array horizontally and makes a new two-dimensional numpy array out of it.

```
array1 = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3]])
array2 = np.asarray([[4, 5, 6]])
array3 = np.asarray([[7, 8, 9]])

concatenated = np.concatenate((array1, array2, array3), axis=0)

print(concatenated)

column_split = np.hsplit(concatenated, array1.size)

td_array = []

for array in column_split:
    td_array.append(array.flatten())

print(np.asarray(td_array))
```

Output of my code:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
[[1 4 7]
 [2 5 8]
 [3 6 9]]
```

How can I do this with less lines of code? I assume it could be very resource intensive, as soon as I apply this example to my larger task.

Comment: I guess the second one is just the transpose of the first result. That is, `td_array = concatenated.T` would be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think 'transpose' was, what I have been looking for.

Comment: When sharing code (or output), you should paste text instead of embedding images whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose using **numpy.hsplit** in this case is not necessary and what I am trying to do is covered by the [numpy.transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html#numpy.transpose) function.

```
concatenated = np.concatenate((array1, array2, array3), axis=0)
td_array = concatenated.T
```

Thank you j1-lee for pointing this out.